# Modifying product collection for list page not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, product-list

I am trying to Modify Product collection which provides collection for product listing page aka category page. For this I have overridden `_getProductCollection` function of `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`. In that function I am trying to do something like below:

```
if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
        }
        $productIds = array();
        foreach($this->_productCollection as $key=>$product)
        {
            $_product = $this->helper->getProduct($product->getId()); // called custom helper function to load product
            if($_product->getAttrCode() !='' && $_product->getAttrCode() == 1)
            {
                $productIds[] = $_product->getId();
            }
        }
        $this->_productCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
        return $this->_productCollection;
```

In `system.log` file, It shows this error - `main.CRITICAL: Illegal state [] []`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I can tell you where it fails.
Once you iterate through the product collection `foreach($this->_productCollection as $key=>$product)` the sql query that retrieves the products is executed and any other filter you add to the collection after this, is useless. It has no effect.
I also see that you are loading each product in the collection separately. This increases the execution time and the resources used by your script.
From what I see in your code, you are trying to filter a collection based on `attr_code`.
I think you can achieve this by marking the attribute `used_in_product_listing` from the backend and just adding

`$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('attr_code', 1);`

Comment: Not getting `attr_code` in `$this->_productCollection` even after enabling `used_in_product_listing` that's why I did that.

Comment: rebuild the indexes

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** :

```
if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
    $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
}
$productIds = array();
foreach($this->_productCollection as $key=>$product)
{
    $_product = $this->helper->getProduct($product->getId()); // called custom helper function to load product
    $attrCode =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attr_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    if($attrCode !='' && $attrCode == 1)
    {
        $productIds[] = $_product->getId();
    }
}
$this->_productCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
return $this->_productCollection;
```

Comment: No, not working.